# Change hyperlink when sending group mails

Tags: php, email

When sending a group mail about assigning to a newsletter, I need to create a hyperlink button which redirects to: `example.com/action.php?id=11 ... email=<%email>`

I need to change the `<%email>` area depending on the recipient's email...

I've done some research, but haven't come up with any solution.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Kindly read the [ask]. You should provide code to us, your are having problems with. You need to clarifiy your question. Otherwise it will be tagged as *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: I'm afraid this questions is extremely vague. If you're already sending email messages in a loop then you must surely be aware of how to use variables and/or arrays. What specific issue are you facing and what research have you done? Are you asking about how to create a custom template language?

Answer (score 0):

assign variable in code eg

```
$email = "someone@somewhere.com";
```

include the variable with the string eg.

```
echo "example.com/action.php?id=11&email=$email";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep something like <%email> as placeholder text in mail body of each mail text in group mail and later you can replace this with your original email by using str_replace() function when you actually sending mail in your loop before sending mail.

provide complete code you are trying to do so we can help you more with it.